# Re-initialize the population in Evolutionary.jl (Julia) - using callback?

Tags: julia, evolutionary-algorithm

Is it possible to **access the current population at the end of each iteration**, for example by using the callback in the Evolutionary.Options (or any other feasible way)?

Say, I want to check the population at the end of each iteration, **and adding new individuals if some conditions are satisfied** (specific to my case).

Thanks